# How to get the result which PP shows in ruby

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have an object which after printing it using PP shows as follow

```
#<Mechanize::Page
  {url
  #<URI::HTTPS:0x3391b60        URL:https://www.something.com/som/postauthentication/postAuthentication.seam?  cid=7375310001974>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title "some"}
 {iframes}
 {frames}
 {links
 #<Mechanize::Page::Link
```

How can I get the URL in an string??

Comment: can you give the code corresponding it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I believe answers your problem using the direction you are following:

```
require 'pp'
require 'mechanize'

a = Mechanize.new 
a.get('http://google.com')
string = PP.pp(a.page, "")
# puts "string #{string}"

if string =~ /URL:(http:.*)}/
  puts "URL: #{$1}"
else
  puts "Didn't find URL"
end
```

But the following answer from @pguardiariois is a better solution - you just want `a.page.uri` here.

Answer (score 1):

That's a Mechanize::Page object, so for example:

```
page.uri.to_s
```